# JSF2 Richfaces 4.1 dynamic select valuechange event not called - inside another form

Tags: ajax, jsf, select

I am invoking a popup from one form. That popup has another form. The popup shows but there is a select box inside the popup which is not working as expected. If the values in the select box are populated dynamically from the backing bean, the value change event is not called for those values. The event is only called for the hard coded `<selectItem />`. See sample code below, so for only `itemLabel="1"` and `itemLabel="2"` the `fBean.onChange` method is called.

The lifecycle phases are not complete for dynamic select items value changes:
First time following are the phases:

START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1 
END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1 
START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6 
END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6

Next time onwards following phases are also added in the middle:  
    START PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2 
    END PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2 
    START PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3 
    END PHASE PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3

I tried `<a4j:log />, <h:messages />`, went through the http post but no clue why is this happening. Will appreciate any help. Thanks

```
<h:form id="aForm">
    <a4j:outputPanel>
        <a4j:commandLink value="show" actionListener="#{aBean.onClick}"
            limitRender="true" render=":fForm"
            oncomplete="#rich:component('fModalPanel')}.show();"/>  
    </a4j:outputPanel>    
</h:form>

<ui:include src="fPopup.xhtml"/>

<!-- Contents of fPopup.xhtml --> 

<rich:popupPanel id="fModalPanel" ...>
    <h:form id="fForm">
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{fBean.selected}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{fBean.selectItems"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2" />
            <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" 
                execute="@this" render="fSubPnl"
                limitRender="true"
                listener="#{fBean.onChange}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>

        <rich:panel id="fSubPnl">
            <h:outputText value="#{fBean.selected}" />
        </rich:panel>

    </h:form>

</rich:popupPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jsf is complex, moved to Angularjs